# How to configure MembershipProvider in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, login-control, authentication

I added a create user and login control wizard to my asp website and attached the database from a previously working solution. But when I try to login with a successfully created user I can't login.

My question is am I missing a step in configuring the login control? I know that it uses the default membership provider but do I need to configure it to recognise the database?

This is the login control declaration:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="Home.aspx" FailureAction="RedirectToLoginPage" Height="161px" Width="450px" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate1" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="#B5C7DE" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333">
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" />
        <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Login>
```

And the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post the error message that is being returned. It is most likely a connectionString issue.

Comment: I get the error thrown by the login control, "Invalid login details". Is there a way I could log the actual error from the login control not just the user error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the connectionString to the Membership database is working, but you may be providing an **invalid username or password**. You can debug this further by implementing the **OnAuthenticate Event**:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You might also consider just **creating a new User** and test logging in with the new username and password vai the **Membership.CreateUser** method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8yy6w3h(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8yy6w3h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this
hope this will help

[How to: Use the ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)